# URL changes but view not changing in my React Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, frontend

**View Not Changing/ React Router Not Working**

*React-router-dom version = 6.4.2*

[My App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4WM4.png)

[login.js & signup.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyEFP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning in either `login.js` or `signup.js`

Comment: i imported both in my app.js but still not able to see content on URL i.e. /login , /signup

Comment: No, but you are missing the keyword return in your components :)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQRF.png)

There is a typo in signup

Comment: I Corrected the typo but not getting the output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try with the following routing code, here Links is the menu component from which you select desired screen.

import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import About from './About'
import Contact from './Contact'
import Products from './Products'
import Links from './Links'
import Clients from './Clients'

function App() {
return (

```
    <BrowserRouter>
            
    <Links/>

     <Routes>
               
     
     <Route path='/About' element={<About/>}></Route>
      <Route path='/Products' element={<Products/>}></Route>
      <Route path='/Contact' element={<Contact/>}></Route>
      <Route path='/Clients' element={<Clients/>}></Route>
            
    </Routes>
 
     </BrowserRouter>  

     </div>
```

);
}

export default App;